# Тире или сложноподчинённое предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

Не убрал за питомцем на улице — получи штраф в 5 тысяч. Правильно ли стоит тире?

Comment: Неправильно опущен восклицательный знак. Форма обращения диктует.

Comment: По-моему, никакого восклицательного знака нет, как и восклицательной интонации : никто не восклицает, не кричит, не восторгается. Интонация спокойна.

Answer (score 1):

Тире стоит правильно, это БСП (бессоюзное сложное предложение) со значением "условие - событие".

Сравнить: Если не убрал за питомцем на улице, то получи штраф в 5 тысяч. Это СПП (сложноподчиненное предложение), ставится запятая при наличии союзов ЕСЛИ, ЕСЛИ...ТО.